# Pymysql Unknow Encoding "latin1"

Tags: python, python-2.x, pymysql

I have experience running pymysql because it always return
the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "synch.py", line 69, in <module>
    db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',user='root',password='mypassword',db='mytable',charset='utf8')
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 327, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 587, in connect
    self._get_server_information()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 976, in _get_server_information
    self.server_version = data[i:server_end].decode('latin1')

LookupError: unknown encoding: latin1
```

Comment: Have you tried `latin-1`?

Comment: yest i have but still the same error